# Approach to avoid overlooking elements while looping over lists and popping elements from the same list

Tags: list, loops, conditional-statements

A common scenario while programming is that, given a list we have to loop over the list and `pop()` elements from the same list when a condition is true.

Now, in such a situation, say for example I have a list `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10]` and the question demands to remove all the elements from the list which are odd.

So, I just take an approach like this.

```
for (int i=0; i<=a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i]%2 != 0) {
        a.removeElementAtIndex(i);
    }
}
```

Now, this would work fine upto `6` in the list `a`.

After that, the loop index would be `6` and that would refer to `7` in the list. As `7` is a odd number it would remove `7` from the list.

Now, the loop index would be `7` and it would point at the `10` in the list. And the element `9`in the list is now at index `6` which is already checked by the loop.

So, this approach would result in a error!

Question: An approach that would not cause the above shown situation and Also make use of only one list and Loop only once over the elements.

Comment: It sounds like you are using JS. Why not use array.filter()? This would iterate over all elements in a and return only those values that match the criteria. So var results = a.filter(function(element) { //logic for returning true if element is even});

Comment: @nraduka It creates a new list by doing so, he wants to change the list in-place.

Comment: If you really insist on not creating a new list - you can decrement `i` every time you remove an item.

Comment: Ahh ok. I misunderstood then @Dean Fenster has the right idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking it is common practice not to change the list which you are currently iterating upon. But to use a new list, or `filter` methods instead.

However, you could decerement the `i` counter every time you remove an item like so:

```
for (int i=0; i<=a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i]%2 != 0) {
        a.removeElementAtIndex(i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

and it should work, but only if you use something like `a.length`, and not a snapshot of the size on the list at a given time.

Edit: In python, because there isn't a c-style for, it would look like this:

```
In [3]: i = 0

In [4]: a = list(range(12))

In [5]: while i < len(a):
   ...:     if a[i] % 2 != 0:
   ...:         a.remove(a[i])
   ...:         i -= 1
   ...:     i += 1
   ...:     

In [6]: a
Out[6]: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Comment: That's an infinite loop! Try it on your own! And the i-- causes the i to be decreased in JS. But in languages like python the i gets decreased only for the current iteration.The next iteration its just the value its supposed to be normally.

Comment: `python` doesn't have this c-style for. So, obviously, it can't be relevant to python.

Comment: @Arunava what language *are* you using. I gave the general approach, as you haven't specified a language.

Comment: I used recursion. To perform this. For every item I remove I checked the next element. And if it is odd too, I poped it out.

Comment: Python @DeanFenster

Comment: Actually, using another list would reduce much of the work, but I wanted to give this approach a shot. Thanks for your suggestions. @DeanFenster

Comment: @Arunava I added an example of how this approach would look in python

Comment: Exactly! That would work. Actually, I was using a for-loop that is why it didn't worked. And, that would actually make the program much short. Thanks @DeanFenster :)